# Is startx deprecated?

Tags: startx

`startx` says:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xinit failed. /usr/bin/Xorg is not setuid, maybe that's the reason?
If so either use a display manager (strongly recommended) or adjust /etc/permissions.local and run "chkstat --system --set" afterwards
```

Obviously, I can `chmod 4775 /usr/bin/Xorg`, which will work until the next Xorg update removes the suid bit again.
However, how to "use a display manager" instead, as "strongly recommended", is not at all obvious to me!

What does this mean?

- Is `startx` *deprecated* now?
- What should I have typed instead?
- Why isn't `startx` doing the right thing then? This is your life saver in case X goes down; likely one of the first commands one has had to learn.

I'm pretty sure my system is using a display manager.
I've got xdm, kdm, gdm, lightdm and sddm.
It boots to a desktop environment, which when logged out of shows a login screen.
In other words, a bog-standard desktop machine setup, but in case it matters, I'm using KDE on OpenSuse Tumbleweed.

I'm going to accept a properly documented, reasonably complete, list of the various *specific commands* that startx has been replaced with, on any Unix. If there is anything that doesn't work exactly like that on OpenSuse, I swear I'll write a bugreport. I hate seeing a user interface that we all seem to know turned upside down for purely technical reasons while nobody knows a replacement.

Comment: Have you seen the section about this change in the [openSUSE 11.4 release notes](http://www.novell.com/linux/releasenotes/i386/openSUSE/11.4/#06)?  It includes instructions on how to set the suid bit permanently.

Comment: @JigglyNaga I think your comment deserves to be an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [11.4 release notes](http://www.novell.com/linux/releasenotes/i386/openSUSE/11.4/#06), yes, `startx` is deprecated in SUSE.  But they explain how to set the setuid bit so that it won't be lost when updating:

> Users who depend on the old configuration can set the setuid bit themselves in `/etc/permissions.local` by removing the comment sign from the following line:
>
> ```
> #/usr/bin/Xorg                 root:root       4711
> ```
>
> and running `SuSEconfig --module permissions` afterwards.

Comment: As for (re)starting the display manager from the command line, I /think/ that would be handled through `systemd` (ie. `systemctl restart <dm>`), but I can't confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! It does answer the first part of the question, though I'm seeking the "strongly recommended" solution.

Comment: I can confirm that `systemctl restart sddm` works, but only after a reboot and `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`. Replacing sddm with kdm or xdm gives a black screen with blinking underscore in the top left corner.

Comment: `SuSEconfig --module permissions` doesn't exist anymore on Tumbleweed maybe?